# My chats isn't displaying in listview using firebaselistadpater

Tags: java, android, firebase

This is my display chat function it didnt display any data also didnt show nay error kindly explain what is the error or mistake

```
private void displayChatMessage() {
ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage> 
().setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class).setLayout(R.layout.list_item).build();
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter= new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
@Override
protected void populateView (View v, ChatMessage model,int position){
TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("DD/mm/yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", 
model.getMessageTime()));
}
};
l.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes  i did but my app start crashing so i remove it. Kindly tell me why it is happening and also better solution

Comment: This is the best solution, but you are probably implementing it in a wrong way. What is the crash?

Comment: i dont know because when i build the project it shows no error but my app doesn't start.

Comment: Did you add ur activity in android manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `startListening()` to be able to start getting data from firebase and displaying it:

> To begin populating data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: where i write and call this method in the above code

Comment: after `setAdapter()` write `adapter.startListening();`